# 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2010

From a few days the SQL server (Win Srv 2008 R2) cannot send e-mail anymore. To send e-mail it connects to Exchange Server 2010 (Win SBS 2011) with the following error. What should I check?

```
250-SBS.<domain>.local Hello [192.168.1.XXX],
250-SIZE,
250-PIPELINING,
250-DSN,
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES,
250-AUTH NTLM LOGIN,
250-X-EXPS GSSAPI NTLM,
250-8BITMIME,
250-BINARYMIME,
250-CHUNKING,
250-XEXCH50,
250-XRDST,
250 XSHADOW,
AUTH LOGIN,
334 <authentication response>,
334 <authentication response>,
Inbound AUTH LOGIN failed because of LogonDenied
User Name: <domain>\<user>
Tarpit for '0.00:00:05',
535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful,
QUIT,
221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel,
Local
```

Thanks.

**EDIT**: Some more specific questions. Is the problem bounded to the Receive Connectors? I have two built-in connectors, 'SBS Default' and 'Windows SBS Internet Receive SBS connector', which one should I check?

**SOLUTION**: We forgot to set the "password never expires" option for the user. This is way it suddenly stopped working "Without changing anything" (this time it was true). This user is not associated to any true employee.

Comment: If your SQL Server is on the same internal LAN as your SBS server, you might need to approve it under "IP Allow List."

Comment: It is listed there... The problem is that after a Windows Update or password change it stopped working.

Comment: Yeah.  Double-check and make sure you really know what the password is on that account.  If so, sometimes the content filter gets "stricter" after an update.  Are these emails going to an account that your server is authoritative for?  (youruser@yourdomain.com)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What should I check?

I think this should be blindingly obvious where to start with checking. The error spells it out:

```
AUTH LOGIN,
334 <authentication response>,
334 <authentication response>,
Inbound AUTH LOGIN failed because of LogonDenied
User Name: <domain>\<user>
Tarpit for '0.00:00:05',
535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful
```

Have you checked the account that SQL is using to send out email? Have you checked the Exchange Server to see if the authentication settings were changed?

edit:
Since you mention the account is set to require TLS, I don't see the STARTTLS verb available and I don't see the TLS session being negotiated in your errorlog. If you are requiring TLS, something changed and that is likely where I would start.

Comment: Nobody changed anything. The account is valid and uses Require TLS authentication. I need to investigate all the options.

Comment: "Nobody changed anything" - If I had a penny for everytime I heard that and found something that WAS changed, I wouldn't need to work anymore. It's not always something obvious that was changed, maybe someone created a new receive connector on the Exchange side, permissions might have changed in the AD or Exchange side, etc..

Comment: You are probably right. Can you provide us a list of things to check in order to solve this issue?

Comment: @alberto I may just be in a bad mood, but my first thought on reading your latest comment is that you should be doing your job, not us.  You check the Exchange server to determine why authentication is suddenly not working... This shouldn't require hand-holding to achieve.